# Using Excel to connect different SQL Server instances (Environments)

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel workbook which is used for data reconciliation from SQL server. There are 3 different environments which I need to reconcile data.

I have a stored procedure which pulls the specific data, Currently my "DATA CONNECTION" is pointing to a TEST Environment. However I need to be able to dynamically change my environment between TEST, UAT, PROD AND DEV.

Can anybody please help me out ?

Comment: So, you have a proc that pulls data from each environment into an excel spreadsheet? The proc lives on each database? Sorry, I'm not quite sure where everything sits and what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: proc is available in TEST and UAT.  Even If I could get to dynamically switch between these two environment - that will be great.

Comment: What is switching dynamically between environments? For example when you run the proc on UAT, do you want that to be extracted out to a specific excel spreadsheet to when you run it on TEST, but you'd like the proc to be exactly the same on both? Sorry if I'm being a bit slow :)

Answer (score 1):

In **Data > Connections** you can see and change your connections.

If you saved your Data Connection to a file (odc) then you can just switch the **Connection file** in the **Connection Properties > Definition**. Otherwise, you can change the **Connection string** itself.